# docker [Errno 2] ip6tables v1.6.1: can't initialize ip6tables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)

Tags: docker, insmod

I am running a docker image in ubuntu with following command

```
sudo docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -it --rm -v $(pwd):/root <docker_image>:ver1.0
```

I get following error

> docker [Errno 2] ip6tables v1.6.1: can't initialize ip6tables table
>   `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)

I googled around and many suggestions were to **disable ipv6** on local machine since ip6 table can't be disabled per container basis.

Finally I found a work around which is to make an entry to **prevent probing ip6table**.

```
sudo modprobe ip6table_filter
```

What is the solution?

Comment: If you need to change the host's firewall settings, you should do it using a program running directly on the host.  A design goal of Docker is that this is difficult to do from inside the container.